# Deriving the mean of truncated $t$ distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, distribution-theory, means

I am trying to derive the mean of right truncated $t$-distribution but cannot solve the integration further. I tried to find the truncated mean as follow:

The pdf of right truncated distribution is;

$\frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)}}{{\sqrt {\pi n} \Gamma \left( {\frac{v}{2}} \right)\left( {1 - \Phi \left( z \right)} \right)}}{\left( {1 + \frac{{{t^2}}}{n}} \right)^{ - \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)}}$

Where  $\Phi \left( z \right)$ is cdf of $t$-distribution

The Mean of distribution is written as;

$E\left( t \right) = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)}}{{\sqrt {\pi n} \Gamma \left( {\frac{v}{2}} \right)\left( {1 - \Phi \left( z \right)} \right)}}\int\limits_z^\infty  t {\left( {1 + \frac{{{t^2}}}{n}} \right)^{ - \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)}}$

Substituting

$k = \frac{{{t^2}}}{n};$

$\sqrt {kv}  = t;$

$dt = \frac{n}{{2\sqrt {kn} }}dk.$

Putting we get;

$E\left( t \right) = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)}}{{\sqrt {\pi n} \Gamma \left( {\frac{v}{2}} \right)\left( {1 - \Phi \left( z \right)} \right)}}\int\limits_{\frac{{{z^2}}}{n}}^\infty  {\sqrt {kv} } {\left( {1 + k} \right)^{ - \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)}}\frac{n}{{2\sqrt {kv} }}dk$

$E\left( t \right) = \frac{{\sqrt n \Gamma \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)}}{{2\sqrt \pi \Gamma \left( {\frac{v}{2}} \right)\left( {1 - \Phi \left( z \right)} \right)}}\int\limits_{\frac{{{z^2}}}{n}}^\infty  {{{\left( {1 + k} \right)}^{ - \left( {\frac{{n + 1}}{2}} \right)}}} dk$

Can someone help me how to solve it further?

Comment: Subsitute $x=1+k$.

Comment: By Substituting $1+k$  $\Rightarrow $


$dz=dk$

Then Applying power rule of integration the final answer is;
$\frac{{{2^{\frac{{n - 1}}{2}}}\sqrt n \Gamma \left( {\frac{{v + 1}}{2}} \right){{\left( {{z^2} + 2} \right)}^{\frac{{1 - n}}{2}}}}}{{\sqrt \pi  \Gamma \left( {\frac{n}{2}} \right)\left( {1 + \Phi \left( z \right)} \right)}}$